# Ng-select display different value than dropdown menu

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I want my `DropDown` to display the property name as `Description`, bind the `id` property to a model and display the the property `ScoreName` of the selected item. Is there a way to achieve that with `ng-select`?

```js
Scores = [
  { id:1, ScoreName:'1', Description:'Bad' }, 
  { id:2, ScoreName:'2', Description:'Good' },
  { id:3, ScoreName:'3', Description:'Best' }
]
```

```html
<ng-select class="score" name="score" appendTo="body" [loading]="!loaded" 
   [items]="Scores" bindLabel="ScoreName" bindValue="ScoreName" 
   placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="row.Score">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: you want item's label is Description and item's value is SocreName?

Comment: bindLabel will show what is displayed in the dropdown and the input field. BindValue will determine what value my ngmodel will recieve. I want my dropdown to show Description values and my input to show my ScoreName

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but maybe it will help someone else.

You can use custom templates as IdiakosE already said.

```html
<ng-select class="score" name="score" appendTo="body" [loading]="!loaded" 
   [items]="Scores" bindLabel="ScoreName" bindValue="id" 
   placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="row.Score">
   <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
    {{item.Description}}
   </ng-template>   
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you still need this you could use custom templates and you cannot use `bindValue` with objects [explanation](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/148). See here for [examples](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/demo/app/examples/custom-templates.component.ts) of custom templates